# Can anyone clarify the rules for $\forall$ intro and elimination, and $\exists$ intro and elimination?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

I am trying to better understand the introduction and elimination rules for quantifiers and in particular the syntax / proof system aspect. I'm currently using Fitch-style proofs.

I asked a recent question with a sample proof and got an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3115673/525966 that I think is a good example.

The rules for $\forall$ and $\exists$ elimination and introduction still confuse me especially since there seems to be a lot of quirky rules about what letters we can use for the... variables, or predicates, or whatever. I honestly can't keep it all straight anymore because I'm so confused. Wikipedia also feels unclear to me. The jump from propositional logic feels massive and rules often seem unclear.

Is there a good explanation somewhere explaining how we can use $\forall$ and $\exists$ introduction and elimination?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, different formal proof systems will do things differently .... but here is how the book I am using ('Language, Proof, and Logic') defines these rules:

First, the system makes the difference between *constants* and *variables* by declaring letters in the beginning of the alphabet ($a$, $b$, $c$, ...) to be constants, and letters at the end ($x$, $y$, $z$) to be variables.

With this difference in mind, we can immediately make sense of the following two formal inference rules:

**Existential Introduction**

$P(a)$

$\therefore \exists x \ P(x)$

This rule says that if some specific object has property $P$, then we know that there is some object that has property $P$ ($P$ here can of course be *any* property (formula) ... and the $a$ is *any* constant (variable-free term)

**Universal Elimination**

$\forall x \ P(x)$

$\therefore P(a)$

This rule says that if everything has property $P$, then any specific one object will have property $P$

Ok, now let's do Universal Introduction. So, here is where you want to be able to prove that all objects have property $P$. How to do this? The strategy the LPL book uses is to say: "Let $a$ be some arbitrary object from the domain. Now, if we can prove that this $a$ has property $P$, then given that we assumed nothing about this object other than that it is some object of the domain, it must be true that all objects have property $P$"

Formalized, this is what it looks like:

**Universal Introduction**

$\quad a$

$\quad ...$

$\quad P(a)$

$\forall x \ P(x)$

So, notice that we are using a subproof structure here. Indeed, the line with $a$ is not a claim, hut rather a kind of assumption that effectively says "let $a$ be an arbitrary object from the domain". Also, to make sure that $a$ is indeed an arbitrary object, you have to make sure that when $a$ is 'introduced' at the start of the subproof, the $a$ is not used outside of that subproof; the use of $a$ is thus limited to the scope of the subproof.

The last rule is:

**Existential Elimination**

$\exists x \ P(x)$

$\quad a \ P(a)$

$\quad ...$

$\quad Q$

$Q$

Ok, so here we are also using a subproof, and again use that a constant $a$ whose use is limited to the scope of that subproof (i.e. does not occur before or after that subproof). As such, we are once again guaranteed that we are not assuming anything about $a$ other than that it is some object from the domain ... except in this subproof we *are* assuming that $a$ has property $P$. So, the first line of the subproof basically says: "Let $a$ be one of those objects that have property $P$ (whose existence is guaranteed by the $\exists x \ P(x)$)".

Now, $Q$ is any arbitrary statement (except, it cannot contain any reference to $a$). And, since the subproofs demonstrates that $Q$ be inferred from the assumption that some object $a$ has property $P$, that means that $Q$ also follows from $\exists x \ P(x)$, because the arbitrariness of $a$ makes $P(a)$ not any stronger of a statement than $\exists x \ P(x)$

Hope that helps!

Here are some sample proofs, btw:

\begin{array}{lll}
1&\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))&Assumption\\
2&\forall x (Q(x) \to R(x))&Assumption\\
3&\quad a&\\
4&\quad P(a) \to Q(a)&\forall \ Elim \ 1\\
5&\quad Q(a) \to R(a)&\forall \ Elim \ 2\\
6&\quad \quad P(a)&Assumption\\
7&\quad \quad Q(a)&\to \ Elim \ 4,6\\
8&\quad \quad R(a)&\to \ Elim \ 5,7\\
9&\quad P(a) \to R(a)&\to \ Intro \ 6-8\\
10&\forall x (P(x) \to R(x))&\forall \ Intro \ 3-9\\
\end{array}

Note that in the above proof it is important to *first* introduce the cnstant used for the universal proof (line 3) and *then* instantiate the universals with that constant (lines 4 and 5); had you put lines 4 and 5 before line 3 then the $a$ would occur outside the scope of the subproof to which its use should be restricted.

\begin{array}{lll}
1&\exists x \ P(x)&Assumption\\
2&\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))&Assumption\\
3&\quad a \ P(a)&Assumption\\
4&\quad P(a) \to Q(a)&\forall \ Elim \ 2\\
5&\quad Q(a) & \to \ Elim \ 3,4\\
6&\quad \exists x \ Q(x)& \exists \ Intro \ 5\\
7&\exists x \ Q(x)&\exists \ Elim \ 1,2-6\\
\end{array}

Also in this proof we made sure to do the universal elimination (line 4) *after* the introduction of the temporary constant (line 3) used to set up the existential elimination. This is something you will learn very quickly: whenever presented with both an existential and a universal, instantiate the existential before the universal.

OK! One more:

\begin{array}{lll}
1&\exists x \ \neg P(x)&Assumption\\
2&\quad \forall x \ P(x)&Assumption\\
3&\quad \quad a \ \neg P(a)&Assumption\\
4&\quad \quad P(a)&\forall \ Elim \ 2\\
5&\quad \quad \bot & \bot \ Intro \ 3,4\\
6&\quad \bot & \exists \ Elim \ 1,3-5\\
7&\neg \forall x \ P(x)&\neg \ Intro \ 2-6\\
\end{array}

This one is interesting in that it shows that you can 'pull out' a contradiction using Existential Elimination.

All right, last one:

\begin{array}{lll}
1&\exists x \ \forall y \ R(x,y)&Assumption\\
2&\quad a \ \forall y \ R(a,y)&Assumption\\
3&\quad \quad b & Assumption\\
4&\quad \quad R(a,b) &\forall \ Elim \ 2\\
5&\quad \quad \exists x \ R(x,b)& \exists \ Intro \ 4\\
6&\quad \forall y \ \exists x \ R(x,y)& \forall \ Intro \ 3-5\\
7&\forall y \ \exists x \ R(x,y)&\exists \ Elim \ 1,2-6\\
\end{array}

Cool ... it uses all four quantifier rules!

Comment: A constant being "some specific/unique thing we actually know the value of" as opposed to a variable whose status is unknown / could-be-anything? Can we re-use constants as long as we're not overlapping contexts? Like could we use $a$ again in some other subproof after your existential elimination example?

Comment: @user525966 Yes!  We can reuse constants exactly in that manner! I didn't want to add that since I felt it was technical enough already, so I am very glad you made this realisation yourself! :)

Comment: And yes, the use of 'constant' is actually a little ambiguous .... outside a subproof the $a$ is used to denote a specific object ... so much like the number $0$ ... but when you use a constant in the temporary context of a subproof for doing universal introduction or existential elimination, it is really much more like a variable ... I compare it to the use of $n$ as in when we do a proof involving numbers and say "Let $n$ be some number" .... it's not a specific number ... and yet it's not quite a variable either ....

Comment: Would this be a valid proof then, using these rules? $\begin{array}{lll}
1&\forall x \ P(x) & Hypothesis\\
2& P(a)& \forall \ Elim \ 1\\
3&\exists x \ P(x) & \exists \ Intro \ 2\\
\end{array}$

Comment: @user525966 Perfect!  Note that this proof does have to assume that there is at least one object in the domain so that the $a$ can actually refer to something ... but most logics make that very assumption ... it's called the Assumption of Existential Import. Logics that do not make this assumption are called *free logics* ... and so in free logics the rules will need to be defined a little differently.

Comment: How do we know the domain? Is there some implicit syntax being omitted in the quantifiers? Like if we have $\forall x$ is this really saying $\forall x \in D$ for some "domain" $D$? Would $D = \emptyset$ reject the Existential Import and make the proof unworkable?

Comment: @user525966 The domain is not specified as part of the syntax.... which makes sense ... logical proofs are supposed to work for *any* domain. For example, no matter what we are talking about, your proof showed that $\exists x \ P(x)$ is true whenever $\forall x \ P(x)$ is true. The fact that most logics do require the domain to be non-empty is really the only requirement made on the nature of the domains

Comment: How does it work when we do see the set-inclusion syntax? Is that some other form or logic or an extension of FOL etc? Sometimes I will see something like $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}, \ x + 1 \gt 0$ and so on.

Comment: Man I wish I could upvote more than once, this answer + the examples + this discussion is really helpful, lol

Comment: @user525966 True ... that would be a *typed* logic

Comment: In one of your examples you have the assumption $a P(a)$, is this functionally the same as assuming some $a$ and then also assuming $P(a)$ on the next line?

Comment: @user525966 Not really ... if this is used to set up an existential elimination, you really want to introduce the constant and the further assumption you are kaking about that constant (that it has property P) at the same time, because that is your way of saying "let $a$ be one of the objects that have property $P$".  But interestingly, this particular system I laid out here does allow you to combine a universal proof with a conditional proof: see the first example proof: on line 3 I introduce the constant itself, but then on line 6 I assume it has property P ... (cont'd)

Comment: Well, you can actually combine those two lines: on line 3 I could immediately have said $a \ P(a)$, and then after elimnating the universals I would get to $R(a)$, and then wrap that all up and say $\forall x (P(x) \to R(x))$. This technique is called a universal conditional proof, as you do both in one ... and this in fact reflects a common proof technique in mathematics. FOr example, to prove that all even numbers are the sum of two odd numbers you would start out with "let $n$ be an even number". The logic statement would be $\forall x (Even(x) \to ...)$

Comment: I am trying to do it that way but I am struggling... is this even close? \begin{array}{lll}
1&\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))&Assumption\\
2&\forall x (Q(x) \to R(x))&Assumption\\
3&\quad a \ P(a)&Assumption\\
4&\quad P(a) \to Q(a)&\forall \ Elim \ 1\\
5&\quad Q(a) \to R(a)&\forall \ Elim \ 2\\
6&\quad Q(a)&\to \ Elim \ 3,4\\
7&\quad R(a)&\to \ Elim \ 5,6\\
8&\quad P(a) \to R(a)&\to \ Intro \ 3-7\\
9&\forall x (P(x) \to R(x))&\forall \ Intro \ 3-8\\
\end{array}

Comment: Like does a $\forall$ intro work too even if it's a $a P(a)$ style assumption as well, as opposed to just $a$? It doesn't seem like it should conceptually if a forall is true for all $x=a$ and not just the ones where $P(a)$ are true (that is, I think I did it wrong somewhere, lol)

Comment: Also what's the last example showing? That the order of quantifiers don't matter? I thought that they did?

Comment: @user525966 You seem to be trying to learn a particular Logic book's approach (or multiple without realizing they differ?) by asking questions without the book. That's a tough road... "How does it work when we do see the set-inclusion syntax?" It could be a typed logic as Bram28 said, but it's more common in Logic to treat those as shorthands: $\forall x\in Y, P(x)$ abbreviates $\forall x(x\in Y\to P(x))$ and $\exists x\in Y, P(x)$ abbreviates $\exists x(x\in Y\land P(x))$. This conveniently keeps "negation swaps quantifiers" true even when sets are around.

Comment: @MarkS. Probably multiple without realizing they different. I sort of gave up on the books because they were so confusing. But yes I am asking how the set stuff factors into the syntax, and your examples make that very clear now, so thank you! Though why isn't it the and operator for both?

Comment: @user525966 If each individual book was confusing, I really wouldn't recommend trying to mix-and-match based on users' preferences... -- If $\forall x\in Y, P(x)$ meant $\forall x\left(x\in Y\land P(x)\right)$, then every statement like $\forall x\in Y, P(x)$ would be claiming that all things (usually sets) $x$ are elements of $Y$ (so $Y$ is a [universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set)), and that they all satisfy $P(x)$; that's not what "$\forall x\in Y, P(x)$" is used in math to mean. "$\forall x\in Y, P(x)$" means that for every $x$ that happens to be in $Y$, $P(x)$ holds.

Comment: @Bram28 Minor correction, second to last proof at the bottom, I believe it only needs a single negative and that's it

Comment: @user525966 Yes, good catch!