How should the $(=)$-introduction and $(\forall)$-elimination rules be modified if wanted to only work with sentences?
The $(=)$-introduction and the $\forall$-elimination rules of inference $\def\f{\phi} \def\tI{\text{I}} \def\tE{\text{E}}$ allow us to deduce formulas with free variables e.g.
$$
\frac{}{(x = x)}(=\tI), \ \ \ \ 
\frac{\forall x (0 \le x)}{(0 \le x)}(\forall\tE).$$
I've been wondering: if we wanted to only work with sentences i.e. formulas in which all variables are bound, how should these rules be ammended? Also, these two are the only rules that would need to be ammended, right?

I describe such a system in my Answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115707/can-anyone-clarify-the-rules-for-forall-intro-and-elimination-and-exists/3115741#3115741   The = Intro rule would be that you can introduce t = t for any variable-free term t

@Bram28: your link doesn't seem to cover the question, which is about an inference system that only works with sentences.

Rules that eliminate quantifiers would also be problematic as they generally deliver conclusions containing free variables. I don't think there is an easy way to present the kind of system you are interested in. Perhaps you could say a bit more about your reasons for wanting a system that only involves sentences.

Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic presents a Hilbert system w/ sentences only, in the section "Properties of First-order Theories" of Chapter 2 (in my copy the axioms are given in Exercise 2.28; each edition is different). One can construct a ND-style system along similar lines, but I don't know a reference where it's actually done. Usually, people who want to restrict to sentences also want to get rid of hypothetical derivations, since these are the same thing in certain interpretations (viz. Curry-Howard). But once you get rid of hypotheticals, you get a Hilbert system anyway.

@RobArthan  OK, maybe I misunderstand what the OP is looking for ... I took it to be that the expression written down in each line of the proof is a sentence, not just any formula. So that's what the system I describe in the link does. It uses subproofs and constants as temporary stand-ins for arbitrary objects inside those subproofs to do universal generalization and existential elimination. So yeah, the structure of the proof is doing a lot of the work.

For a proof system that uses sentences, see George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, Computability and Logic (Cambridge UP, 5th ed 2007), Ch.14 Proofs and Completeness.
